# Spring MongoDB Saving Enum Keys Of Map in double quotes

Tags: java, spring-mongodb

I have a class WebIntegration in that i have field "f" which is Map[FeatureType, Feature]. Normal enum fields are saved correctly but when i have a key as enum in map it is saved in double quotes

This is code i am using:

```
SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "test_database");
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(simpleMongoDbFactory);
Integration integration = //integration;
mongoTemplate.save(integration);
```

The document gets saved like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bc5855b610be4b5e225f422"),
  "_class" : "com.demo.WebIntegration",
  "ttl" : "Elixir",
  "iT" : "web_integration",
  "f" : {
      ""page_feature"" : {
          "iGW" : false,
          "isSV" : false,
          "iFCT" : "page_feature",
          "e" : true,
          "_class" : "com.demo.WebIntegrationPageFeature"
      },
  "a" : true,
  "cTm" : NumberLong("1539686608262"),
  "uTm" : NumberLong("1539686608262"),
  "iD" : false
}
```

Same enum is used in field "iFCT" which gets saved correctly but the key in field "f" is saved with double quotes.

Due to this at fetch time it breaks because there is no enum like page_feature with quotes.

If i register custom converters, it works perfectly fine. But i wanted to know if normal fields are saved properly then why the keys of map are not saved properly if they are enum.

Am i missing something ?